# how to store checked value of listview in array or database?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview whose rows has one textview and a check box.

I want to pop the name associated with the checkbox and on a click of a button i want to store all the textview data in to database. How would I do this?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this if it wasn't crucial: Check your spelling before posting.

Comment: check this question: it sure help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481066/android-multiple-selection-listview-textview

Comment: Keyser: thanks.. ill remember that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
    View view = listview.getChildAt(position);
    TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.myTextBox);
    String contents = text.getText().toString();
}
```

You will need to tweak the if statement to your own checkboxes and iterate through them to check are they checked and rename the code in the if statement to your oen names

Comment: but how to do it for every checked item in listview is single click