# Add custom CheckBox to ListView

Tags: android, checkbox, adapter

I add new CheckBox in getView() (PlanAdapter class)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Plan entry = listPlan.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.walkRow, null, false);

        }
        LinearLayout d = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxPlace);


        TextView distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
        distance.setText(" " + entry.getexerciseNumber());

        TextView time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setText(" " + entry.getwholeTime());

        CheckBox chckStart = new CheckBox(context);
        chckStart = entry.getCheckBox();
        chckStart.setFocusable(false);
        d.addView(chckStart); //here i get force close
        return convertView;
    }
```

when I scroll down it looks fine, but when I back and scroll up it crashes.

getter, setter in Plan class

```
public CheckBox getCheckBox(){
        return checkBox;
    }

    public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox){
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
    }
```

and my checkBox in Main class

```
    for (byte i = 0; i < db.planView.size(); i++) {
        chcBox = new CheckBox(this);
        chcBox.setId(i);
        checkboxList.add(chcBox);

        listOfPlan.add(new Plan(db.planView.get(i).getText().toString(), db
                .count(db.planView.get(i).getText().toString(),
                        getApplicationContext()), chcBox));

    }
```

log: `http://wklej.to/RpBvr/html`

Comment: can you post error logs...Please.

Comment: please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10481066/1168654

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add each checkbox to multiple parent views, which you cannot do...

However a ListView already has many features to implement checkboxes, here is one way:

```
public class Example extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] array = {"one", "two", "three"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, array);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.v("Example", "ItemClick: " + ((ListView) parent).getCheckedItemPosition());
    }
}
```

You can customize the layout simply by passing your own XML file.

**Addition**

Each time a row is shown you refresh the `entry` data and try to add the checkbox, which is why you can scroll down but not up. If you want to keep your custom adapter, simply check to see if the row has already been initialized before trying to add the same values again.