# How to add to List item a checkbox

Tags: android

I have `Layout` with `ListView` and in bottom there is `EditText` field where user can write down title and add new item in `ListView`. I the List item there is title but I want to add checkbox too. This is my code :

```
protected void addItemList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (isInputValid(etInput)) {
    itemArrey.add(0,etInput.getText().toString());
    etInput.setText("");

    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

How can I add a checkbox?[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685366/customised-listview-using-arrayadapter-class-in-android/16686623#16686623. check this might help

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom adapter and add your views in the getView method (i.e., EditText and your Check boxes)
 So whenever you call your setadapter method it will get added to your view

Comment: You mean like in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733601/add-custom-checkbox-to-listview

Comment: @BeginnerAndroid did you try the link i posted?

Comment: the solution is nice but create the custom view like the user has questioned it. and do settag inside the convertview and then do after getTag.If u still didn't get it .just lemme know i'll share the code

Comment: @BeginnerAndroid yup thats why i posted a snap shot also

Comment: @BeginnerAndroid i tested now on my device works fine. post your code. you might me doing it the wrong way

Comment: @Raghunandan when i paste your code eclipse threw me that I need to import many things - I did it - but then I have to create new methods do I have to do it?

Comment: @BeginnerAndroid no need not create any methods

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31334/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-beginnerandroid)