# ListView with label, message, name and How to add button below the List

Tags: android

I need to create a

> ListView

Each item of list should contains three fields

1-Label

2-Message

3-Name

How to do that ,i do not have any idea.

Any good suggestion.

Comment: [Let me do it For You?](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

Comment: thanks ,but these fields should be textview

Comment: hey this is just normal thing please search this on google you find someting... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558101/1168654 and http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2011/09/custome-listview-with-hashmap-1-go-to.html and http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html and http://mobile.dzone.com/news/custom-listview-android and http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: you can find A LOT OF EXAMPLES!! try them fist.

Comment: @UP VOTER: PLEASE first learn about UP VOTING!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom listview for doing this and use below reference links for custom listview.

[Custom Listview 1](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/custom-listview-android)

[Custom Listview 2](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

Comment: Custom ListView 1 have problem deny to add items list.add(temp)..having problem

Comment: red line under add()...deny to add

Comment: how can i add button below the ListView.

Comment: post your xml file, so i will help you.

Comment: <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:layout_weight="2"
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
 </ListView>
<TextView  android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#FFff00"
    android:text="No data"
    />

Comment: post your xml file or tell which layout are you using so i will help you.

Comment: Dipak can you tell me in that Custom ListView1 ..why they are using HashMap<String,String>..this concept is not clear

Answer (score -3):

create a list item layout xml & design it with label, message & name. Use the xml in adapter. use the adapter in listview as `myListView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: he dont kno any thing about Custom Listview then what to do?? how he kno what is ADAPTER?? how create list item in layout??