# Customizing ListView Items with 3 TextView

Tags: android, listview, customization

I have a table in my db and i query the table (selecting 3 text fields of my table) and save all querying results from my cursor to 3 separate lists. (each list for saving one field values) now i want to show this results in a ListView that each row of it has 3 TextView and each TextView shows one item of my lists (each row of ListView has one item from each list, so each row has three TextView)... 
any help? Regards...

Comment: check this que it may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/q/10481066/1168654

Answer (score 0):

you need to built a custom Adapter and a CacheView to use your custom layout in the your listView.
Here: http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/
you may find a good tutorial with in a project example in attachment.