# Wrong Checkbox selection in Android?

Tags: android, list, listview, checkbox

In my Apps, I am selecting the Items to Order. My Problem here is If I check the Checkbox to Order even another Checkbox is also has been checked. Means If I select single Item , two Items are getting checked.

And starting for 5 Items it is checked correctly and displaying in the Ordering page. From 6th Item If I select It is displaying some other Items in the Ordering page.

Here is my Code of the List:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (view == null) {         
              view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.appetiserlistview, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.appetiserimage);
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.appetisertext);
            viewHolder.desc=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.appetiserdesc);
            viewHolder.price=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.appetiserprice);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.bcheck);


            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }






        viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);

        viewHolder.price.setText(prices[position]);
        viewHolder.desc.setText(descs[position]);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(itemnames[position]);
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(itemnames[position]);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                {
                    arr.add(itemnames[position]);
                    itemprice.add(prices[position]);
                       image.add(bmps[position]);


                }
```

Comment: here is a nice example http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list/7738854#7738854

Answer (score 0):

AS per behavior of listview, it does not save state of its item as they Inflayet on scroll time, so you should use a array of boolean values to persist status of check boxes,

```
public class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private boolean isCheck[] = new boolean[Data.fbFriendList.size()];
 // Data.fbFriendList is arraylist contains data
    public FriendListAdapter() {

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        Arrays.fill(isCheck, Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Data.fbFriendList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View hView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            hView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_item, null);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.profile_pic = (ImageView) hView
                    .findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
            holder.name = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) hView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            hView.setTag(holder);
        }

        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) hView.getTag();

        if (isCheck[position]) {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        try {
            holder.profile_pic.setImageBitmap(Utility.model.getImage(
                    Data.fbFriendList.get(position).getFbFriendFBid(),
                    Data.fbFriendList.get(position)
                            .getFbFriendThumbImgUrl()));
            holder.name.setText(Data.fbFriendList.get(position)
                    .getFbFriendName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            holder.name.setText("");
        }

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.checkBox.isChecked())
                    isCheck[position] = true;
                else
                    isCheck[position] = false;
            }
        });

        return hView;
    }

}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView profile_pic;
    TextView name;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
```

Here isCheck[] is a boolean array used in Adapter class to persist status of checkboxes and Data.fbFriendList is a arraylist.

Comment: @Anand Tiwari Thank you for your reply. I will try now.

Comment: @Anand Tiwari Can you tell me how to hold the Status of Checkbox in CustomAdapter?

Comment: just create a array of boolean values itemChecked[]  in BaseAdapter class (in constructor) and initialize by false values for initially unchecked, and then use in getView().

Comment: I changed in Adapter class but in getView I am getting like this: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to boolean

Comment: Boolean[] itemChecked = new Boolean[size];
Arrays.fill(itemChecked, Boolean.FALSE); add this to ur adapter.

Comment: @Anand Tiwari As you told I did but still I am not able to solve it. I am getting force close before I enter to the Selecting the List of Items Activity.. :( As I am new to Android not able to solve that issue.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I have posted complete adapter class just change array list by your list, its working at my end, further if you get any issue, let me know.

Comment: @Anand Tiwari ya okai I will try it now.

Comment: @Anand Tiwari what is ??getFbFriendFBid() , getFbFriendThumbImgUrl() and getFbFriendName() ..

Comment: these are bean function, used to retrieve values, you should replace them by your data(whatever you using) or customize getView() as per your need...

Comment: @Anand Tiwari Can you see my ListView class posted to my Question and tell me what I have to replace in the place of those functions??

Answer (score 0):

Its a basic property of `ListView` 
not only `checkboxes` but also `Edittext` and `other input controls` will have the same value as the one have 
what actually happen in `list view`

the items that are being displayed are only created.

When you `scroll` them new items are created so as per previous display state the one of check box get checked for current display.
**Solution 1:**
Create a `list` in which `store the states of all checkboxes(or list items)` and at calling of `bindview() method` check the status of check box and according to the list check and uncheck them also create `checkbox listener` so that `oncheckchange` event change the state of checkbox(or listitem) in list so this way you can get the solution

**Solution 2:**

if you need only one check box then you can use listview property that enables multi item selection

**Edit 1:**

set this property

```
android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
```

for you its 2

[Follow the Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)
and also [See this Property](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)

Comment: See this - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:choiceMode

Answer (score 0):

you have to save states of all of your checkboxes and restore them accordingly. Here is an example i have already posted. If any problem you are facing then let me know. I will try to help you.

Check this link

[How to implement a button that gets all checkbox's state and adds the value of checked item into arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190083/how-to-implement-a-button-that-gets-all-checkboxs-state-and-adds-the-value-of-c/10191369#10191369)