# Creating a ListView with Checkboxes

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with each item containing an image, a textview and a checkbox. I am trying to have it so wherever you click within the item it highlights the checkbox. As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121192/android-custom-listview-unable-to-click-on-items) response I set the focusable attribute of the checkbox to false, but I am still only able to click the checkbox to change its state. What's even more interesting is when I click on a checkbox every proceeding 10th item is also highlighted. Any suggestions?

Here is my xml for an item.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip" 
        android:src="@drawable/stub"   
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" 
        android:textSize="20dip" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Clear Cache"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This one looks similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925119/every-seventh-box-checked-with-checkboxes-in-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a `CheckableLinearLayout` or `CheckableRelativeLayout` for your `ListView`'s item layout container,
2. set your listview's mode to 'multipleChoice'

find more details in the links below:

- http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/
- http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/

Answer (score 0):

in the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="450dp" 
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

     <ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_weight="1"/>
     </RelativeLayout>



     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="450dp" 
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

     <Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Clear Cache"/>
     </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this help you...

Comment: I am a bit confused by the way you typed that out, can I get a bit of clarification?

Comment: I think is the same problem, if you want to put your a button over your principal listview xml, do something like this (check my update answer)

Comment: and maintain my other type of xml for your checkbox, and o course put your sizes values for the RealtivesLayouts.

Comment: Tried that also, didn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

in the process of populating the list, you can set a `OnItemClickListener` and change the checkbox to `checked`. try something like this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                ListItem item = (ListItem) adapter.getItem(position);
                if(item.checkbox.isChecked()) 
                      item.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                else
                      item.checkbox.setChecked(true);
            }
 });
```